# How to use existing 3-layered logic in ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web Pages 2 projects?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-webpages

I have 5 basic projects that need to be part of multiple applications. WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF depending on the needs we have.

These Projects are:

```
Company.Business - Business Logic DLL
Company.Business.Model - Business Models 
Company.Business.DAL - Various DALs 
Company.Configuration.Classes - Classes that are used to initialize BOs 
Company.Utilities - General Utilities
```

I know need to create some simple apps so i dont want to go down the road of MVC and decided to do them in Web Pages 2. Soon i wil have to create 1-2 MVC applications to do some more complicated stuff.

So basically my question is what is the recommended way of using my existing architecture to these 2 cases?

Lets say i reference all of the above to my web site project. Then what?

Where i should initialize my Business Layer object? In every page? Once somewhere? (Web Pages case)

I suppose that in MVC applications i would just initialize my Business layer object in every controller constructor?

Comment: Can you post an example of a method in your `Company.Business` assembly? This would help with answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a service oriented layering (not to be confused with SOA ) where the composition of your business objects will happen (repositories, mappers etc) into services. This is nothing more than a container or your business objects and it will be the entrypoint for accessing the business logic of you application. 
You will then consume the services from within you pages code behind or inside your controllers. Passing to it it's dependencies with a DI framework.  Here's a simple service to consume within your app.

```
public class SampleRepository : ISampleRepository
{
   public void Insert(Sample item)
   {
       //do something, save the item ?        
   }
}


public class SampleService : ISampleService 
{
   private ISampleRepository _repository;

   public SampleService(SampleService repository)
   {
        _repository = repository;
   }

   public void DoSomething(Sample item)
   {
       //put some logic here, validation , logging, etc..
        //.....

       //Call the repositoey      
       _repository.Insert(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes it will, Web Pages are a simplified version of WebForms with html and razor mixed within the same page. Once you got the service project referenced in your site you can then initialize a service instance from within the razor in the page.

Comment: So i will have to make a new Business Object in EVERY page load?

Comment: Web pages and WebForms aren't the same. WebPages do not have a Page_Load.http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/aspnet-web-pages-(razor)-faq#Whats_the_difference_between_ASP.NET_Web_Pages,_ASP.NET_Web_Forms,_and_ASP.NET_MVC

Comment: I dont want to use webforms i dont like their philosophy, so i want to go with web pages for simple apps and MVC for the bigger ones.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for MVC is to use dependency injection like Ninject. If you want to setup quickly, use the MVC 3 nuget package of Ninject. After that is installed, you can inject the implementation of you business layer into your MVC controller.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC3/

Comment: Currently i dont want to go into Inversion of control. I am struggling to just bring my existing libraries to live inside simple ASP.NET apps (Web Pages 2 and MVC). I just want to know howi should handle the "life" of my objects and where...